# How to var_dump all instantiated objects in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am currently debugging an application developed by someone else in Laravel 5. 
We have a lot of classes created in many files.

I have difficulty to follow all the code so I was thinking that first I could display all the objects and variables which are instantiated in my view. 
How can I var_dump all the objects instantiated?

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://php.net/get_defined_vars

```
$arr = get_defined_vars();
```

Comment: this doesn't seems to work. I have <?php get_defined_vars(); ?> in my Laravel view but it doesn't display anything.

Comment: you need to capture the output in a variable and then print it, see my answer

Comment: if you want to execute php code in a laravel view (blade) just do '@'php and '@'endphp and place your specific php code in there. Rest of sietse's answer is perfect, so go for it. (without the quotes around the at-sign, otherwise it wouldn't post...